# jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.2.3 limite para consulta

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Galera uso o jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.2.3 do Jörn Zaefferer.

Queria saber como fazer para ele realizar a consulta apenas se eu informar mais de 3 caracteres.

Chama o plugin desta forma:

```
$("#suggest5").autocomplete('completar.php', {
                width: 600,
                multiple: false,
                matchContains: true
            });
```

Comment: O "basta usar" é uma resposta?

Comment: sim achei a solução e editei a pergunta.

Comment: Mas aqui é um Q&A e não um fórum amigo, você tem que formular uma resposta. Mesmo que tenha sido você quem perguntou, somos diferentes de outros site faz o tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

da pra fazer assim:

```
 if($("#suggest5").lenght>3){   
        $("#suggest5").autocomplete('completar.php', {
                        width: 600,
                        multiple: false,
                        matchContains: true
        });
    }
```